# Restore a vote of an answer after the question has changed

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, down-votes, 408-timeout

I downvoted an answer because it was by far not a good answer, other answer were much better.

But then the questioner edited his question (not the answer) which left the downvoted answer the only possibly answer. I wanted to remove my vote but to much time had past.

The max. time to restore votes is now depending on when the answer was modified. What about connecting this time also to when the question was modified?

**EDIT**

I know about the workaround (edit the answer a little bit), but I am asking a feature-request: If an Question is modified, we should be abled to revote on the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Just do a dummy edit and you'll be able to revoke your downvote.

There are very few cases where there is nothing to improve in an answer. Add links. Improve grammar/formatting. Add some extra details. There should be *something* you can improve.

If not, one can try adding Oxford commas or something, though making trivial edits to revoke downvotes is discouraged.

---

Allowing the lock to be lifted will open the system up to abuse. The reason for the lock in the first place is that people downvote competing answers, accumulate more votes due to the sorting, and then revoke the downvotes. Currently, if they want to revoke the downvotes they have to edit each and every answer. With the feature request, they can just edit the question and then revoke.

Comment: Same thing I did, removed fullstop from an answer, revoked my upvote, again added the fullstop. But for this you must have enough reputations.

Comment: @Manishearth: I know about the workaround, but I was asking for a features request: When an Question changes, we should be allowes to modify the votes of the Answers.

Comment: @MartinMulder: it's a very rare use case. Not enough to merit this change, since it can very easily be abused by system gamers

Comment: @Manishearth: Can you explain how it can be abused? I do not see how...

Comment: @Manishearth: Good point :)

Comment: If dummy edits are discouraged, why are you recommending them?? :(

Comment: @hayden: I'm not. I'm recommending substantial fixes. I said that one _could_ do it, but it's discouraged. OK to do so imho.

Comment: "Just do a dummy edit and you'll be able to revoke your downvote." reads like a recommendation to me. Maybe "Treat this as an opportunity to improve this answer.." would be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You should revert the question to its previous state or flag for moderator attention, because if OP change the question that much it changes the complete aspects then it should not be an edit but the new question.

Comment: it depends. It looks like the OP is talking about a _clarification_ which validated the answer.

Comment: but that would not make a wrong answer to be correct :S

Comment: not necessarily

Comment: It was not a wrong answer, it just wasn't as good as the others

Comment: then it should not be downvoted because down-voting in for wrong answer not an alternate answer.

Comment: one can downvote whatever they want, I have downvoted short answers in the past.

Comment: one can do this, but this is wrong because if you hover down-vote you would see **This answer is not useful**

Comment: @Manishearth Often short answers can be considered not useful because they give no explanation of why this solution works or what was going wrong for OP etc. => irritating, not useful.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed: No, it's not wrong (http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz). Sometimes there are useful answers that are only marginally useful.

Comment: @hayden: Yes, exactly. These get downvoted. However, if suddenly it is the _only_ answer to a question, one may want to reconsider their vote.

Comment: @Manishearth I don't see why being the only answer is a special case here. (If the answer isn't improved it doesn't deserve a +1).

Comment: @hayden: not a +1. But maybe a revocation of the -1.